# Проверка массива в массиве и удаление элементов

Tags: javascript, массивы

Необходимо найти в массиве элементы (тоже массивы) с повторяющимся элементом 0 и отсеять их из общего массива.

`let arr = [[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]];`

В данном массиве нужно отсеять все элементы, где есть повтор 0 друг за другом.

`let arr = [[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0]];`

Вроде бы ничего сложного, но убил на это 3 часа времени и решил параллельно более сложные задачи, но не эту.

Comment: `arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
  var prev;
  item.forEach(function(item1, i1, arr1) {
   if(item1 == prev && item1 == 0){
     delete arr[i];
    }
   prev = item1;
  });
});`

Comment: Не беситесь, ребята, почти в начале обучения JS нам сказали написать функцию, выводящую уникальные варианты расстановки массива без повтора одного элемента. Решать логичнее было бы по формулам комбинаторики, но я решил наглядно разложить массивы. Спасибо за код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без претензий на эффективность кода, зато просто.

```js
let arr = [[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]];

var result = arr.filter(function(v){
   return v.join('').indexOf('00') == -1;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: А что если там 10?

Comment: @Qwertiy что 10 ?

Comment: Вставить разделитель и отфильтровать по индексу с разделителем. Это именно то, что мне было нужно, спасибо.

Comment: @teran, число 10. Не вижу в вопорсе что в массиве только 0 и 1.

Comment: @STL, два нуля в начале или конце не забыл проверить?

Comment: @Qwertiy да понял уже :)

Comment: @Qwertiy разделитель можно добавить в начало и конец строки

Comment: @teran, я знаю. Но это не означает, что он про это не забыл.

Comment: @Qwertiy Не забыл, потестил и с "100". Мой Годзилла работает. Задача изначально ставилась для 0 и 1 и решения там на 5 строк. Но чукча пока не очень умный и ставит эксперименты, зная 10% синтаксиса.